# Accidentally ran pod update instead of pod install. Is there any way to revert?

Tags: cocoapods

I accidentally ran `pod update` instead of `pod install`, and now I have compile errors in my project.

Is there any easy way of reverting to my previous pods?

I'm thinking of hacking it -- I have my Podfile.lock file under source control, so I can grab the version numbers off that, then lock down the Podfile to those numbers e.g.:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.3'
```

But is there a simple command like `pod revert` or `pod undo` or something?

Otherwise I'll probably just suck it up and update my project code to be compatible to the new pods.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you use git or other version control system, just reset changes in `Podfile.lock` and run `$ pod install` in terminal.

Comment: This isn't ideal, because it relies on prior changes being committed. The other answers which suggest to remove the `pods` directory work regardless of commit...

Comment: what does reset changes mean?

Comment: @MohsinKhubaibAhmed , discard changes in `Podfile.lock` that appeared after `pod update` and have not been committed yet.

Answer (score 5):

You can go through the version changes in the `pod install`'s output and rewrite your podfile with the desired versions.

---

For example:

In `pod install` output below, `SwiftSpinner` was updated from `0.9.5` to `1.0.2`

[image]

Therefore, in the `podfile` change the line

```
pod 'SwiftSpinner'
```

to

```
pod 'SwiftSpinner', '0.9.5'
```

and run `pod update` again.

---

Now, you might get errors reverting certain pods:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `Realm (= 1.0.2)` required by `Podfile`
>
> - `Realm (= 1.1.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`

In such a case, close `Xcode`, delete your `podfile` and run `pod install` again.

Comment: Although not downvoting, but this is wrong as of now; source : https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to remove the pods directory from your project and update and install it again.

```
rm -rf Pods 
bundle exec pod repo update
bundle exec pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following files and folders:
  - xcworkspace
  - Podfile.lock
  - Pods (Folder)

After, run:

```
$ pod install
```

This seems like something risky, but really it is not. I do it all the time

Comment: Well, `.xcworkspace` is literally **generated** by cocoapods, and the rest too, so it shouldn't be a problem...