# iOS - many errors after pod update

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

After doing in mistake pod update to all pods started getting many errors

this are some of them:
[image]

This is the pod update command :
[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: If you use git or other version control system, just reset changes in Podfile.lock and run $ pod install in terminal.

Comment: Couple of solutions available in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068944/accidentally-ran-pod-update-instead-of-pod-install-is-there-any-way-to-revert

Comment: @Sateeshso rm -rf Pods
did the work but can you explain what was the deal there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the one that helped me is this line:
rm -rf Pods

fixed everything

Answer (score 0):

Exit Xcode, then run this commands in Terminal and project folder:

```
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
pod install
```